# How to extracting content from pagination next button?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

This is the website I am trying to scrape:
(https://www.jurongpoint.com.sg/store-directory/?level=&cate=Food+%26+Beverage)

Below is the code that I have tried,but it repetitively return me first page and third page.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

def parse():

    base_url = 'https://www.jurongpoint.com.sg/store-directory/?level=&cate=Food+%26+Beverage'
    url="https://www.jurongpoint.com.sg/store-directory/?level=&cate=Food+%26+Beverage&page=3"


    while True:
        html = urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html ,"html.parser")

    
        for link in soup.find_all('div',class_='entry-content'):

            try:
                shops=soup.find_all('div',class_="col-9")
                names=soup.find_all('tr',class_="clickable")

                for n, k in zip(names, shops):
                    name = n.find_all('td')[1].text.replace(' ','')
                    desc = k.text.replace(' ','')
                    print(name + "\n")
                    print(desc)
                
            except AttributeError as e:
                print(e)

        
            next_button = soup.find('a', href=True)

            if next_button:
                url = base_url + next_button['href']
            else:
                break

parse()
```

Answer (score 0):

Select your elements more specific, used [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) here to get the `<a>` that is child of an element with `class="PagedList-skipToNext"` :

```
next_button = soup.select_one('.PagedList-skipToNext a')
```

Also check the results of your selection, `base_url` is not needed here:

```
url = next_button.get('href')
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def parse():
    url = 'https://www.jurongpoint.com.sg/store-directory/?level=&cate=Food+%26+Beverage'

    while True:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)
        
        print(url) ## to see what you are working on or enter code that should be performed            

        next_button = soup.select_one('.PagedList-skipToNext a')
        if next_button:
            url = next_button.get('href')
        else:
            break

parse()
```

##### Output

```
https://www.jurongpoint.com.sg/store-directory/?level=&cate=Food+%26+Beverage
http://www.jurongpoint.com.sg/store-directory/?level=&cate=Food+%26+Beverage&page=2
http://www.jurongpoint.com.sg/store-directory/?level=&cate=Food+%26+Beverage&page=3
http://www.jurongpoint.com.sg/store-directory/?level=&cate=Food+%26+Beverage&page=4
http://www.jurongpoint.com.sg/store-directory/?level=&cate=Food+%26+Beverage&page=5
http://www.jurongpoint.com.sg/store-directory/?level=&cate=Food+%26+Beverage&page=6
http://www.jurongpoint.com.sg/store-directory/?level=&cate=Food+%26+Beverage&page=7
http://www.jurongpoint.com.sg/store-directory/?level=&cate=Food+%26+Beverage&page=8
http://www.jurongpoint.com.sg/store-directory/?level=&cate=Food+%26+Beverage&page=9
http://www.jurongpoint.com.sg/store-directory/?level=&cate=Food+%26+Beverage&page=10
http://www.jurongpoint.com.sg/store-directory/?level=&cate=Food+%26+Beverage&page=11
http://www.jurongpoint.com.sg/store-directory/?level=&cate=Food+%26+Beverage&page=12
http://www.jurongpoint.com.sg/store-directory/?level=&cate=Food+%26+Beverage&page=13
http://www.jurongpoint.com.sg/store-directory/?level=&cate=Food+%26+Beverage&page=14
```