# How to stop scraping empty pages in category?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pagination, categories

I am trying to scrape content from 4 category.Yes,the scraping for 4 of the category worked.The thing is I want to prevent non-existing pages to be scrape but my code below does not work. The reason for the range for loop to be 15 is because my fnb pages got 14.

fnb:
14 pages

services:
1 page

electronic:
2 pages

fashion:
4 pages

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def parse():

    cate=["Services","Food & Beverage","Fashion & Accessories","Electronics & Technology"]
    url = "https://www.jurongpoint.com.sg/store-directory"

    for cat in cate:
        for page in range(1, 15):
            
                print(f'Scraping category {cat} page {page}')
                payload = {
                    'level': '',
                    'cate': cat,
                    'page': page
                }
                resp = requests.get(url, params=payload)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
            

                for link in soup.find_all('div',class_='entry-content'):

                        try:
                            shops=soup.find_all('div',class_="col-9")
                            names=soup.find_all('tr',class_="clickable")

                            for n, k in zip(names, shops):
                                name = n.find_all('td')[1].text.replace(' ','')
                                desc = k.text.replace(' ','')
                                print(name + "\n")
                                print(desc)

                        except AttributeError as e:
                            print(e)

parse()
```

This is a portion of my output from the code above:

[image] <- Output show scrapping of empty pages

Comment: In addition - On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the type of output you are after. However, the following implementation should help you get rid of empty content issues.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.jurongpoint.com.sg/store-directory"
categories = ["Services","Food & Beverage","Fashion & Accessories","Electronics & Technology"]
payload = {'level': '','cate': '','page': ''}

def parse():
    for cat in categories:
        for page in range(1, 15):
            print(f'Scraping category {cat} page {page}')
            payload['cate'] = cat
            payload['page'] = page
            resp = requests.get(url, params=payload)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
            if not soup.select("table.table > tbody"): 
                break

            for item in soup.select("table.table > tbody"):
                try:
                    shop = item.select_one("div.col-9").get_text(strip=True)
                except AttributeError: shop = ""
                try:
                    name = item.select_one("tr.clickable > td:nth-of-type(2)").get_text(strip=True)
                except AttributeError: name = ""
                print(shop,name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parse()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: Number of pages can also increase and you will loose results - So wouldn't it be easy to use the approach already answered https://stackoverflow.com/a/75200178/14460824 to avoid the static range values in general? Just add the scraping part that extracts the necessary parts.

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

data = []

def parse(c):
    url = f'https://www.jurongpoint.com.sg/store-directory/?level=&cate={requests.utils.quote(c)}'
    while True:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)

        for e in soup.select('tbody:not([id])'):

            data.append({
                'name':list(e.stripped_strings)[0],
                'desc':e.find_next_sibling('tbody').get_text(strip=True)
            })
        next_button = soup.select_one('.PagedList-skipToNext a')
        if next_button:
            url = next_button.get('href')
        else:
            break
    return

for c in ["Services","Food & Beverage","Fashion & Accessories","Electronics & Technology"]:
    parse(c)

data
```

##### Output

```
[{'name': 'Keyshoe',
  'desc': 'Our full range of services includes key duplication, access cards and auto gate access setup. Keyshoe also provides dyeing, cleaning and repair services for a wide range of products, ranging from sofas, handbags, luggage, shoes, belts and other leather goods.'},
 {'name': 'LA Barbershop',
  'desc': 'LA Barbershop is one of the first few brands in town to offer a complete bespoke grooming experience for men, from shaving to haircut, massage to ear-cleaning services at value for money prices. Its concept is inspired by the traditional English barbershop culture that dates back to 18th century.'},
 {'name': 'My Digital Lock',
  'desc': 'My Digital Lock specialise in Gateman, KEYWE Smart Home, EPIC and Samsung Digital Lock with Digital lock installation for EC Condo and BTO HDB Fire Rated Main Door in Singapore'},
 {'name': 'POSB', 'desc': ''},
 {'name': '4Fingers Crispy Chicken',
  'desc': 'Hand-painted crispy chicken with a twist!!    All outlets in Singapore are halal.'},...]
```